# In AQL, do joins happen first or the filters?

Tags: arangodb, aql, nosql

I have 2 collections, users and employees, such that _id of the employee document is embedded in user document. I was wondering which of the two below is more efficient way to do it.

```
FOR employee IN employees
    FOR user IN users
            FILTER user.email == 'user@foo.com'
    FILTER employee._id == user.employee
RETURN merge({user: user, active: employee.active})
```

OR

```
FOR user IN users
    FOR employee IN employees
            FILTER employee._id == user.employee
    FILTER user.email == 'user@foo.com'
RETURN merge({user: user, active: employee.active})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it doesn't matter. The query will be automatically optimized from the database execution planner and rewritten to a query that looks similar to the following.

```
FOR employee IN employees
  FILTER user.email == 'user@foo.com'
  FOR user IN users
    FILTER employee._id == user.employee
    RETURN merge({user: user, active: employee.active})
```

You can check how a query is optimized over the webUI in the `query` tab with the button `explain`. It will print you the execution plan where you can also see  which indexes are used and how much every part of your query costs. It's a very powerful tool.

If you want to know more about query execution and performance you should take a look into the [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/current/AQL/ExecutionAndPerformance/).